# Can not upload Resume from computer to a SO job application form

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I am trying to apply for a job I found on SO Jobs, but unfortunately it seems to be impossible due to some errors, I am not sure if it is an internal server error or it is about my local machine, I tried to turn off the antivirus but it does not work so I guess it is not related to my antivirus.

Technical details:
File format: **PDF** ||
Upload option: **Computer**

Here is a screenshot of the error message that shows up:

[image]

Comment: OS and browser versions please

Comment: @SamuelLiew **Windows 8.1 Professional** , **Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.92 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

Comment: Have you tried a different browser, such as Firefox?

Comment: @Jonathan.Rosa Yes I tried. (sorry I forgot to mention that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** this was due to a bug handling anonymous applications; an expected cookie was not consistently written to the response and if it wasn't there the upload would fail. Fix has been deployed as of 2020-04-15 16:00 UTC.

There’s been a few problems with the backend that provides virus scanning of uploaded content due to an issue in a third party component. While we work with the vendor to get the issue addressed we need to manually poke the service with a pointy stick to get it fully functioning again.

That poking happened yesterday so things should be up and running again, apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thank you for your effort Dean, but sorry it is not working.

Comment: @John looking at your traffic I see that you're attempting to apply using a different browser that isn't logged into the site. I've just reproed not being to apply anonymously and am getting a fix together now

Comment: Yes I can confirm that I am not applying using my SO profile. But when I try to apply I always use the same tools (and their versions) I mentioned above. Hopefully, It gets fixed ASAP. Thank you so much.

Comment: @John fix is under review, should be in production within the hour

Comment: It is fixed now, thank you so much. Have a great day!